# PHP error 404 in form open and the submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, http-status-code-404

I'm stuck in this error. When I click on Submit button, I received a 404 page not found. It should have uploaded the picture, imputed at file open.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="uploads/.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="stuff"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="ceva" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    //$size = $_FILES['file']['size']
    //$type = $_FILES['file']['type']

    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    if (isset ($name)) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $location = chmod("C:\xampp\htdocs\CeTXT\uploads", 777); 

            if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'uplods';    
            }
        } else {
            echo 'please choose a file';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why is your form action set to `uploads/.php`?  Remove that `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

By:

```
if(isset($_POST['ceva'])){
```

You are not using the right POST name even for the _FILE field.

Answer (score 0):

**Your improved HTML:**

```
<form action="uploads.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="stuff"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="ceva" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

**Your improved uploads.php file:**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['ceva'])){
  $name = $_FILES["stuff"]["type"];
  //$size = $_FILES['stuff']['size']
  //$type = $_FILES['stuff']['type']

  $tmp_name = $_FILES['stuff']['tmp_name'];
  $error = $_FILES['stuff']['error'];

  if (isset ($name)) {
  if (!empty($name)) {

  $location = chmod("C:\xampp\htdocs\CeTXT\upload\", 777); 


  if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
    echo 'uplods';    
  }

    } else {
      echo 'please choose a file';
      }
  }
     }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your form action seems to be set to uploads/.php, maybe this needs to be uploads.php?

Comment: @dvdpearson. I tried to replace 'submit' with 'ceva', but I still get the 404 error

Comment: @AbdulWahhabQureshiI. I also replaced uploads/.php with uploads.php and I receive the same error